# ASP.NET MVC with Composite Web Client application block

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcsf

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, I want to develop an asp.net page/Shell , the shell will host multiple UI/components.I discovered 'Webclient software factory' .I wanted to know if asp.net MVC is supported by WCSF?

Answer (score 0):

No not out of the box, but it is possible to modify it
Look at this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1232612.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blaine/archive/2010/03/22/will-wcsf-vs-2010-version-support-unity-2-0-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: the sent dates back to 2008 , we have new WCSF since , released feb 2010.Is it still not supported ?

Comment: Didn't i answer your question since you've unaccepted my answer?

Comment: AFAIK no it is not, but I would still say it is modifiable.
Why not just use MVP anyway? I know it is not quite the same implementation, but based on the same principles

Comment: I wanted Composite UI components and i love MVC . Now i have to decide between the two :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it 100% correct this time , ASP.NET MVC has got inbuilt hooks for DI .For this specefic requirement check ASP.NET MVC **Areas** :)